# Can I make a fancy divider with CSS which doesn't disappear on zoom?

Tags: html, css

I have horizontal separators in a web application. I wanted them to look somewhat nicer than a plain line, but not over the top, so I gave them a gradient.

Then I noticed that when the browser zoom is changed, some of the lines disappear. I guess that when they get smaller than 1 px, the browser is rounding some of the heights to 0 px.

This is a quite unpleasant side effect. Unstyled `<hr>` tags don't disappear at any zoom, but I have to give mine a height, else they don't display at all.

Is there a way to correct the problem and always have the line at exactly one pixel height, no matter what the zoom is? Solutions don't need to support IE8 and below.

```
hr.fancyDivider {
border: 0;
min-height: 0.0625em;
 background: linear-gradient( to right, rgba(0,71,185,0), rgba(0,71,185,0.9), rgba(0,71,185,0));
margin-bottom: 2em;
```

}

And a fiddle using them: http://jsfiddle.net/U7cv6/. Zoom out a few steps to see the problem.

Comment: [off-topic] You aren't defining gradients properly. `background: linear-gradient( to right, rgba(0,71,185,0), ...);`

Comment: What @NiettheDarkAbsol meant was, you aren't using any standard property so you should use the standard one and can get rid of proprietary ones

Comment: OK, I changed it to the standard property, thanks for the info.